# Azure Auth error: Multiple types were found that match the login provider named 'facebook'

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm running into an error when trying to authenticate a user via Facebook using the Azure Mobile Services built in APIs. I've looked through my packages and can't see any reason why I'd have two providers as suggested in the error:

> Multiple types were found that match the login provider named
>   'facebook'. This can happen if multiple login providers are defined
>   with the same name but different casing which is not supported. The
>   request for 'facebook' has found the following matching login
>   providers:  Facebook Facebook.

I did create a branch that upgraded to the App Services and then reverted back to AMS instead. I'm wondering if something is lingering which is causing the problem.

My package list is as follows:

- Autofac{3.5.2}
- AutoMapper{3.2.1}
- EntityFramework{6.1.1}
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights{1.0.0}
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept{0.17.0}
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector{1.0.0}
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.JavaScript{0.11.0-build09387}
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector{1.0.0}
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web{1.0.0}
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.TelemetryChannel{1.0.0}
- Microsoft.AspNet.Cors{5.2.2}
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core{2.0.1}
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin{2.0.1}
- Microsoft.AspNet.Razor{3.2.2}
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client{5.2.2}
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core{5.2.2}
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors{5.2.2}
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData{5.2.2}
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin{5.2.2}
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing{5.2.2}
- Microsoft.Data.Edm{5.6.2}
- Microsoft.Data.OData{5.6.2}
- Microsoft.Data.Services.Client{5.6.2}
- Microsoft.Owin{3.0.0}
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb{3.0.0}
- Microsoft.Owin.Security{2.1.0}
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory{2.1.0}
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies{2.1.0}
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook{2.1.0}
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google{2.1.0}
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt{2.1.0}
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount{2.1.0}
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth{2.1.0}
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter{2.1.0}
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager{2.0.3}
- Newtonsoft.Json{6.0.4}
- Owin{1.0}
- RazorEngine{3.4.1}
- Sendgrid{6.1.0}
- SendGrid.SmtpApi{1.3.1}
- System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt{3.0.2}
- System.Spatial{5.6.2}
- WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend{1.0.470}
- WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Entity{1.0.470}
- WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Storage{1.0.470}
- WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Tables{1.0.470}
- WindowsAzure.ServiceBus{2.3.4.0}
- WindowsAzure.Storage{3.1.0.1}

Is there anything here which could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Having compared with an older version of the project, it looks to not be related at all to my packages. Instead the problem was caused by adding the login provider within the WebApiConfig class.

Removing the following resolved the issue:

```
options.LoginProviders.Add(typeof(FacebookLoginProvider));
```